# Sequences satisfying gcd(S(x), S(y)) = S(gcd(x,y))

Tags: nt.number-theory

Consider the sequence S(x) = 2^x - 1. This sequence has two interesting properties:

a) If the GCD of S(x) and S(y) is S(gcd(x,y)), and

b) For any prime p, S(p-1) is divisible by p.

Property a follows from the fact that if 2^x is 1 mod n and 2^y is 1 mod n, 2^(gcd(x,y)) is 1 mod n. Property b follows from Fermat's little theorem.

I am interested in sequences that exhibit property a but also have a modified form of property b such as
b*) For any prime p, S(p-2) is divisible by p.

Does anyone know of any such sequences?

Comment: There are many such sequences, a^n - 1 being a form which leads to the study of cyclotomic polynomials.  The Fibonacci numbers (and certain other solutions of recurrences) are a disguised form of a^n - b^n, and also have the property.  I do not know the most general form of such sequences. Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.05.25

Comment: well, those sequences satisfy the first property but not the second one. For example, if $p|a^{p-2}-b^{p-2}$ then $p|a-b,$ which holds only for finitely many $p.$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A *strong divisibility sequence* is a sequence of positive integers $(a_n)_{n\ge1}$ with the property that $\gcd(a_n,a_m)=a_{\gcd(n,m)}$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_sequence.
(Strong) divisibility sequences tend to arise from algebraic groups, including sequences such as $a^n-b^n$, Fibonacci (and similar) sequences, elliptic divisibility sequences, etc. I'm not sure about your second condition. For elliptic divisibility sequences, there's a large literature on which terms are divisible by $p$, but it generally won't be the $(p-2)$'nd term. See
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_divisibility_sequence, especially the section on EDS over finite fields.